# arduino-mode Emacs file specification error

Tags: emacs, arduino

When I try to edit an Arduino Sketch (*.ino file), I get this error:

```
Eval error in the ‘c-lang-defconst’ for ‘c-constant-kwds’ in arduino-mode:
Eval error in the ‘c-lang-defconst’ for ‘c-basic-matchers-before’ in arduino-mode:
Eval error in the ‘c-lang-defconst’ for ‘c-matchers-2’ in arduino-mode:
File mode specification error: (invalid-function (append (quote (HIGH LOW INPUT OUTPUT INPUT_PULLUP LED_BUILTIN true false)) (c-get-lang-constant (quote c-constant-kwds) (quote (cc-langs)))))
```

This happens even on the stock examples->basic->Blink.ino file.

My .emacs.d/init.el file contains these lines:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.\\(pde\\|ino\\)$" . arduino-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(autoload 'arduino-mode "arduino-mode" "Arduino editing mode." t)
```

I can't find a '`c-matchers-2`' file.

This is Emacs 26.1.

Can anyone point me in a direction to fix this error?

Thanks in advance for your help and advice.

-Kevin

Comment: What happens when your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` contains _only_ the two lines you posted above?

Comment: Same exact error message.

Thanks for the diagnostic.

Comment: Are you using the most current version of `arduino-mode`? Using the version from [elpa](https://elpa.gnu.org) and a basic init file, I don't run into any errors.

Comment: FYI `c-matchers-2` is a variable defined in `cc-mode` which `arduino-mode` should be pulling in.

Comment: @nega, I can't find the `arduino-mode` in the elpa collection at https://elpa.gnu.org/. When Browsing the packages, nothing returns when searching for '`arduino`'. - - I'm using version 1.0, copyrighted in 2008 by Christopher Grim. The first executable line is, `(require 'cc-mode)`

Comment: ah, my bad, it's at https://melpa.org. (local confusion, sorry). Assuming you have melpa in your list of package sources, if you do `M-x list-packages` then `r` to refresh your package list, then search for `arduino-mode` you should have 20180509.36 in the version column. If you installed by hand, you can get the current version from https://github.com/stardiviner/arduino-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nega, you were right, it was a version issue. When I used `M-x list-packages`, I saw I had installed version 20151017.2335, and the most current was 20180509.36 by stardivirer. arduino-mode packages are in the melpa repository.

Thanks so much for your help in pointing me in the right direction.

-Kevin